# Custom Twitter Parse Login in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I want to create custom view controller twitter Parse login. I do not want to use default "loginViewController" fields provided by Parse. I also want to extract user's screen name and profile picture from twitter and save it in Parse. Here is my code.

```
//SignInController for custom Parse SignIn
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Parse
import ParseUI

class SignInController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var fbLogin: UIButton! //Facebook login button
@IBOutlet weak var TwitterLogin: UIButton! //Twitter login button
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SignIn: UIButton! //Custom SignIn button for Parse
@IBOutlet weak var signUp: UIButton! //Custom SignUp button for Parse

var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView=UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Do additional setup after loading the view.
    self.actInd.center=self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped=true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(self.actInd)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //Dispose any resourses that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func FBLoginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
//Facebook login
}
@IBAction func TwitterLoginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
//Here I want to implement twitter login
}

//Custom Parse SignIn
@IBAction func SignInAction(sender: AnyObject) {       
    var usernamefield=self.username.text
    var passwordfield=self.password.text
    if (count(usernamefield.utf16)<4 || count(passwordfield.utf16)<5)
    {
     alert("Invalid", message: "Username must be greater than 4 and password must be greater than 5")
    }
    else
    {
    self.actInd.startAnimating()
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernamefield, password: passwordfield, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
        if((user) != nil)
        {
            self.alert("Success", message: "Logged In")
        }
        else
        {
            self.alert("Error", message: "\(error)")
        }
    })
    }
}

//Create Account or SignUp Controller
class CreatAccount: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signUp: UIButton!
var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView=UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Do additional setup after loading the view.

    self.actInd.center=self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped=true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(self.actInd)  
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //Dispose any resourses that can be recreated.
}
//Custom Parse SignUp
@IBAction func signUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var usernamefield=self.username.text
    var passwordfield=self.password.text
    var emailfield=self.email.text
    var confirmpasswordfield=self.confirmPassword.text

    if (count(usernamefield.utf16)<4 || count(passwordfield.utf16)<5 || count(confirmpasswordfield.utf16)<5 )
    {
        alert("Invalid", message: "Username must be greater than 4 and password must be greater than 5")
    }
    else if(count(emailfield.utf16)<8)
    {
        alert("Invalid", message: "Please enter a valid email")
    }
    else if(passwordfield != confirmpasswordfield )
    {
        alert("Invalid", message: "Passwords mismatch")
    }
    else
    {
    self.actInd.startAnimating()      
    var newUser=PFUser()    
    newUser.username=usernamefield
    newUser.password=passwordfield
    newUser.email=emailfield
    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
        if((error) != nil )
        {
            self.alert("Invalid", message: "\(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            self.alert("Success", message: "Signed Up")
        }
    })
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the question – does this code not work in some way? If so, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: In parse tutorial, you use default twitter login button. That button automatically creates twitter login with parse using PFloginViewController. I do not want to use PFloginViewController. I designed my own controller and its twitter button. There are online examples that show custom parse login without using PFloginViewController but there is no online example l that shows custom twitter login with using default Parse twitter button.

Comment: If somebody do not understand. Just watch these two tutorials. 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnf7KHHeiO0. 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sL47vpWTMU.

Comment: If this is intended as a “how to do this” question and answer, the way to do this is to self-answer your own question, i.e. post a question “how do I do X” and then also post an answer below saying how to do it. See the [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) FAQ.

Comment: Yes, I answered but please do not hurry to rate the question because it takes time to build a stack overflow profile.

Comment: I have to point this out, Swift does not provide a default "loginViewController"... that's provided through the 3rd party library you're using. There is no default "loginViewController" in the iOS SDK, or Swift language for that matter....

Comment: @ TheCodingArt. Sorry, Actually it is only a writing mistake. I will edit it. It is provided by Parse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer for my question. Check TwitterLoginAction.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Parse
import ParseUI

class SignInController: UIViewController 
{
@IBOutlet weak var fbLogin: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var TwitterLogin: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SignIn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var signUp: UIButton!

var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView=UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Do additional setup after loading the view.
    self.actInd.center=self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped=true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(self.actInd)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //Dispose any resourses that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func FBLoginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
} 
@IBAction func TwitterLoginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock { (user, error) -> Void in
        if (user==nil) {

            println(user)
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.")
            return;

        } else if ((user?.isNew) != nil) {
            println("User signed up and logged in with Twitter!")
        } else {
            println("User logged in with Twitter!")
        }
    }
}

//Parse SignIn
@IBAction func SignInAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var usernamefield=self.username.text
    var passwordfield=self.password.text

    if (count(usernamefield.utf16)<4 || count(passwordfield.utf16)<5)
    {
     alert("Invalid", message: "Username must be greater than 4 and password must be greater than 5")
    }
    else
    {
    self.actInd.startAnimating()
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernamefield, password: passwordfield, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
        if((user) != nil)
        {
            self.alert("Success", message: "Logged In")
        }
        else
        {
            self.alert("Error", message: "\(error)")

        }
    })
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for Twitter Login in **Swift 3**

```
PFTwitterUtils.logIn { (user, error) in
        if (user==nil) {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.")
        } else if ((user?.isNew) != nil) {
            print("User signed up and logged in with Twitter!")
        } else {
            print("User logged in with Twitter!")
        }
    }
```